# Excel Worksheet SelectionChange event doesnt get fired firsr time but works second time

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-addins

I have a winform dialog in my excel add-in, which is popped up on click of a panel button. I have a selection change event added to worksheet. The event is not being fired first time. I have to close the dialog and the open it again, This time it will work. Am I missing something here, or it is bug with excel interop API?

Enviornment:Excel 2007, .NET 4.0, Interop runtime: v1.1.4322

Following is the code

```
public partial class CreateColumn : Form

    {

    public CreateColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        //Bug: this event does not fire the first time.. works on second time.
        ws.SelectionChange += new   Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(ColRangeSelChange);

    }

    public void ColRangeSelChange(Excel.Range target) 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(target.AddressLocal);
    }}
```

This is how Create Column is being called

```
 private void smartTemplateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Range SelectedRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
      if (SelectedRange != null)
      {
           List<string> DataSetLabels = new List<string>();
           foreach (Range cell in SelectedRange.Cells)
           {
                if (cell.Value2 != null && !cell.Value2.Equals(""))
                {
                    if (!DataSetLabels.Contains(cell.Value2))
                    {
                        DataSetLabels.Add(cell.Value2);
                    }
                }
           }
           if (DataSetLabels.Count > 0)
           {
               PopupCreateColumnDialog(DataSetLabels);
           }
      }
 }

 public void PopupCreateColumnDialog(List<string> DataSetLabels)
 {
      if (DataSetLabels.Count > 0)
      {
           CreateColumn colDialog = new CreateColumn();
           colDialog.TopMost = true;
           colDialog.Show();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Your code seems right. Your problem might be provoked either because CreateColumn() is called wrongly (either too late or more than once, etc.) or because you are declaring another event affecting somehow the behaviour of this one (e.g., exiting the application). You have to write more code or explain how this part is called a bit better in order to get quick help.

Comment: @varocarbas Hi thanks for the reply. I have edited the post to show how the dialog is being called

Comment: From what I understand from this code: firstly you are connecting to the given spreadhseet (and defining a Excel.Worksheet variable); you are getting certain ranges from this variable (all the selected cells); once certain condition is met (DataSetLabels having more than one element), you call the Columns bit; in this part, you assign the worksheet (which, presumably, is the same one than before) and the event. My question is: why you are not assigning the event (this one and any other one you will be using) when defining the spreadsheet for the first time?

Comment: @varocarbas Actually I have to get the address to selected range and push it in one of the textbox of the create column dialog. Remember how we select the range while defining a formula,chart etc , the same functionality I want. If I attach the event before the dialog is instantiated i wont be able to push the value in text box on selection.

Comment: Also it is an application level addin so there can be any number of sheets, that is why I am taking Active Sheet on the run and assigning the events to it.

Comment: I am writing my reply. Give me some minutes.

Comment: Done. Logically you are accessing at the application level, how are you planning to access Excel otherwise? This has nothing to do with relying on ActiveSheet; you can do this every time you want, or rely on a different reference. What you need is to put a bit of order and just define the variables/events once (at the start). What happens with your dialogs (in your form) does not have anything to do with Excel; the Excel information is stored in Excel-variables if you make these variables accessible (for example: global declaration), you wouldn't find any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comments, I think that this problem (and others which might potentially come up) derives from a non-too-good communication with Excel. Thus, this question will consist just in showing you a structure which shouldn't provoke any problem.

Right at the start of the application (or when you start to analyse the given Excel file), you have to define the Excel Object, the WorkBook and the Worksheet you will be dealing with (the first one). I will focus on the Worksheet by following your example:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
ws.SelectionChange += new   Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(ColRangeSelChange);
```

Where `ColRangeSelChange` is defined by:

```
public void ColRangeSelChange(Excel.Range target) 
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(target.AddressLocal);
}
```

While you deal with this spreadsheet you don't need to change this definition. Now the given method (`ColRangeSelChange`) is associated with the given event (ColRangeSelChange) and will be called every time, the event is triggered. If you keep redefining the Worksheet and the Event, you might get in coordination-related problems and weird situations might occur.

If you want to account for a different spreadsheets (via `ActiveSheet` again, or by any other mean), you would have to redo this process again (variable assignation and event assignation) with other variable or by keeping the same ones.

Summary: remove both Worksheet and Event definition from `CreateColumn()`. Put this right before starting to interact with the given worksheet (before `smartTemplateBtn_Click`). And make sure that you define events just once (at the start) and that you assign the given worksheet to a variable just once (at the start).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, let me restructure my code and try this out.

Comment: Yes it worked, It was the right approach. Now I am iterating through the sheets in the starting and I attached event to them. Now it works consistently. However it works only in debug mode and that to when I put breakpoint in the event handler, I am looking into this, but previous issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for help.